# why does wba exel code show me <> when i add an espace after the last letter of the word

Tags: excel, vba

Why does `if` condition show me `<>` when I add an `" "` after the text

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub KoppelStelle()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Pin_Number_1 As Integer
    Dim Pin_Number_2 As Integer
    Dim Pin_Number_Max As Integer
    
    Dim Wire_1_1 As Integer
    Dim Wire_2_1 As Integer
    Dim Wire_3_1 As Integer
    Dim Wire_1_2 As Integer
    Dim Wire_2_2 As Integer
    Dim Wire_3_2 As Integer
    
    Dim Wire_Count_1 As Integer
    Dim Wire_Count_2 As Integer
    Dim Wire_Count_Max As Integer
    
    m = 1
    k = 1
    Pin_Number_1 = 0
    g = 1
    Pin_Number_2 = 0

    
    Kopp_Kurzname_1 = InputBox("Enter Kopp_Kurzname", "Kopp_Kurzname 1")
    Kopp_Kurzname_2 = InputBox("Enter Kopp_Kurzname", "Kopp_Kurzname 2")
    Pin = InputBox("Enter Pin Number", "Kopp_Pin Number")
    Sheets.Add.Name = "KoppelStelle"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Wirelist_1"
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Wirelist_2"
    
    For i = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
       For j = 1 To 11
          Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m, j) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j)
       Next j
       For j = 1 To 11
          Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m + 1, j) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j)
       Next j
       
       Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m + 1, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m + 1, 4) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m + 1, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 8)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m + 1, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m + 1, 7) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(m + 1, 8) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5)
       m = m + 2
    Next i
    m = 1
    For i = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
       For j = 1 To 11
          Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m, j) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j)
       Next j
       For j = 1 To 11
          Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m + 1, j) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, j)
       Next j
       
       Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m + 1, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 6)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m + 1, 4) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 7)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m + 1, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 8)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m + 1, 6) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m + 1, 7) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4)
       Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(m + 1, 8) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 5)
       m = m + 2
    Next i
    
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Wirelist_1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Kopp_Kurzname_1 = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(i, 4) Then
            If Pin_Number_1 < Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(i, 5) Then
                Pin_Number_1 = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(i, 5)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Wirelist_2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Kopp_Kurzname_2 = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(i, 4) Then
            If Pin_Number_2 < Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(i, 5) Then
                Pin_Number_2 = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(i, 5)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
 
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    If Pin_Number_2 > Pin_Number_1 Then
        Pin_Number_Max = Pin_Number_2
    End If
    If Pin_Number_1 > Pin_Number_2 Or Pin_Number_1 = Pin_Number_2 Then
        Pin_Number_Max = Pin_Number_1
    End If
    
    'MsgBox "Pin_Number_Max ="
    'MsgBox Pin_Number_Max
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
    For j = 1 To Pin
    
        Wire_Count_1 = 0
        Wire_Count_2 = 0
        Wire_1_1 = 0
        Wire_2_1 = 0
        Wire_3_1 = 0
        Wire_1_2 = 0
        Wire_2_2 = 0
        Wire_3_2 = 0
        
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
        For i = 1 To Worksheets("Wirelist_1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        
        'MsgBox "Line ="
        'MsgBox Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(i, 5)
        'MsgBox "j ="
        'MsgBox j
        
            If Kopp_Kurzname_1 = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(i, 4) And Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(i, 5) = j Then
                Wire_Count_1 = Wire_Count_1 + 1
                If Wire_Count_1 = 1 Then
                    Wire_1_1 = i
                End If
                If Wire_Count_1 = 2 Then
                    Wire_2_1 = i
                End If
                If Wire_Count_1 = 3 Then
                    Wire_3_1 = i
                End If
                
            End If
        Next i
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
        
        For i = 1 To Worksheets("Wirelist_2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If Kopp_Kurzname_2 = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(i, 4) And Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(i, 5) = j Then
                Wire_Count_2 = Wire_Count_2 + 1
                
                If Wire_Count_2 = 1 Then
                    Wire_1_2 = i
                End If
                If Wire_Count_2 = 2 Then
                    Wire_2_2 = i
                End If
                If Wire_Count_2 = 3 Then
                    Wire_3_2 = i
                End If
                
            End If
        Next i
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    
        If Wire_Count_2 > Wire_Count_1 Then
            Wire_Count_Max = Wire_Count_2
        End If
        If Wire_Count_1 > Wire_Count_2 Or Wire_Count_1 = Wire_Count_2 Then
            Wire_Count_Max = Wire_Count_1
        End If
        'MsgBox "pin"
        'MsgBox j
        'MsgBox "Wire_Count_Max ="
        'MsgBox Wire_Count_Max
        'MsgBox "Wire_1_2 ="
        'MsgBox Wire_1_2
        'MsgBox "Wire_2_2 ="
        'MsgBox Wire_2_2
        'MsgBox "Wire_3_2 ="
        'MsgBox Wire_3_2
        
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
        For i = 1 To Wire_Count_Max
            If Wire_1_1 <> 0 And i = 1 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 1) = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(Wire_1_1, 1)
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(Wire_1_1, 5)
            End If
            If Wire_1_1 = 0 And i = 1 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 1) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
            End If
            
            If Wire_2_1 <> 0 And i = 2 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 1) = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(Wire_2_1, 1)
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(Wire_2_1, 5)
            End If
            If Wire_2_1 = 0 And i = 2 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 1) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
            End If
            
            If Wire_3_1 <> 0 And i = 3 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 1) = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(Wire_3_1, 1)
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = Worksheets("Wirelist_1").Cells(Wire_3_1, 5)
            End If
            If Wire_3_1 = 0 And i = 3 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 1) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
            End If
        Next i
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    For i = 1 To Wire_Count_Max
            If Wire_1_2 <> 0 And i = 1 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 3) = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(Wire_1_2, 1)
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(Wire_1_2, 5)
            End If
            If Wire_1_2 = 0 And i = 1 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 3) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
            End If
            
            If Wire_2_2 <> 0 And i = 2 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 3) = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(Wire_2_2, 1)
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(Wire_2_2, 5)
            End If
            If Wire_2_2 = 0 And i = 2 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 3) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
            End If
            
            If Wire_3_2 <> 0 And i = 3 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 3) = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(Wire_3_2, 1)
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = Worksheets("Wirelist_2").Cells(Wire_3_2, 5)
            End If
            If Wire_3_2 = 0 And i = 3 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 3) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
            End If
        Next i
        
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
        If Wire_Count_1 = 0 Or Wire_Count_2 = 0 Then
            If Wire_Count_1 = 0 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(1 + Wire_Count_Total, 1) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(1 + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
                
            End If
            If Wire_Count_2 = 0 Then
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(1 + Wire_Count_Total, 3) = "-"
                Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(1 + Wire_Count_Total, 2) = j
            End If
            If Wire_Count_1 = 0 And Wire_Count_2 = 0 Then
                Wire_Count_Total = Wire_Count_Total + 1
                
                
                
            End If
        End If
        
        Wire_Count_Total = Wire_Count_Total + Wire_Count_Max
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------'
    Next j
    
    For i = Worksheets("KoppelStelle").UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        If Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + 1, 2) Then
            Range(Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i, 2), Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Cells(i + 1, 2)).Merge
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Range("A:C").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Worksheets("KoppelStelle").Range("A:C").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I count at least 36 different `If` conditions in the code you pasted, so it isn't clear which condition you are referring to.

But generally speaking, a word with a space is not equal to the same word without a space. Spaces are important for comparing text, counting length, delimiting text, etc.

To ignore leading and/or trailing spaces, use `Trim`, `LTrim` or `RTrim`.